# Перемещение маркера по карте leaflet (openstreatmap)

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, leafletjs

Добрый день!

Как сделать так чтобы пользователь мог перетащить маркер по карте и его координаты отправились Ajax на сервер?

Карта leaflet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо подписаться у объекта на событие dragend.

```
var marker = L.marker([0,0], {draggable: true});
marker.on("dragend", function(e){
   var newCoords = e.latlng;
});
```

Думаю, как отправить запрос, разберётесь.